# Guava cache with size set to 5000 caches only 3600 entries

Tags: java, performance, caching, guava

I created a test setup with 5000 unique requests through a loading cache.
I then played back the same 5000 requests again and expected the hit-rate to be 50%.

It turns out that the hit-rate was 36% at the end of two runs.
So, around 1400 requests lead to loading of data again on second execution.

Also, entry expiration could not have been an issue, as the expireAfterWrite was set to 60 minutes and the whole execution took less than 30 minutes.
Cache size was set to 5000. So, all 5000 should have remained in cache for at least an hour.

What am I missing here?

Cache Code:

```
public class TestCache {
    private static final CacheLoader<Req, Resp> OBJ_CACHE_LOADER = new CacheLoader<Req, Resp>(){
        @Override
        public Resp load(Req requestObj) throws Exception {

            return (new MyOwnObject()).processRequest(requestObj);
        }       
    };

    private static final LoadingCache<Req, Resp> OBJ_CACHE = CacheBuilder
            .newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(5000)  
            .recordStats()
            .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES) 
            .build(OBJ_CACHE_LOADER);

    public Resp get(Req requestObj){
        Resp res = null;

        try{
            res = OBJ_CACHE.get(requestObj);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Test program:

```
public class TestObjCache2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            double start = 0d;
            double now = 0d;

            start = System.nanoTime();
            for(int i=0;i<5000;i++){
                try{ anObjWhichCallsThroughCache.get(i); }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e); }
            }
            now = System.nanoTime();

            try{

                System.out.println("\n\n\n\nNo more hits should go to external system\n\n\n");
                Thread.sleep(10000);                
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            start = System.nanoTime();
            for(int i=0;i<5000;i++){
                try{ anObjWhichCallsThroughCache.get(i); }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e); }
            }
            now = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println( (now-start)/1000000.0 );            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: @MitchWheat Could you take a look now?

Comment: i did some basic example based on your code, i have a cache size of 4977. thus i have only a few missing. are you sure your list of inputs is persistent (hash codes do not change) you may check this separately you may output the caches size

Comment: 3600 is suspicious because that's the number of seconds in an hour!

Comment: i did some more measurements. i indeed have similar misses as well. maybe the maximum is really a upper bound

Comment: Javadoc on `maximumSize`: "Note that the cache may evict an entry before this limit is exceeded. As the cache size grows close to the maximum, the cache evicts entries that are less likely to be used again. For example, the cache may evict an entry because it hasn't been used recently or very often."

Comment: Can we see the `hashCode` and `equals` method of the `Req` class?

Comment: Both request and response are complicated objects with JAXB annotations. But, the hashCode is based on 6 fields (string) which don't change in value. Same fields are used in the equals method also. I would have to type lot of mock code to fairly represent what is going on.. because I cant share real code!

Comment: @MitchWheat Actual hit rate was 35.6% for 10000 requests. So, it was close to 3600 not exact. I got this from Guava's cache statistics.

Comment: I read somewhere that Guava uses segmented concurrent hashmap. Is there any size restriction at each segment level?

Comment: Update: With cache size as 5000 and 1000 unique requests, cache works perfectly - not even single miss in second run. So, maximum size seems a rough number at best. There seems to be no other problem with the hashCode or equals.